# Old facebook sdk is not working on ios 6 device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am using Old facebook sdk for implemnt facebook app on my application.

This is my code

```
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"!!!!!!!"];



    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    // [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    NSString *accessTokenString = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    NSDate *expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    if([accessTokenString length]>0 && expirationDate != nil)
    {
        accessToken =accessTokenString;
        _expirationDate =expirationDate;
        hasFBLoggedInBefore=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        hasFBLoggedInBefore = NO;

    }
    NSArray *permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"offline_access",@"publish_actions",@"email",@"publish_stream",nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];

    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
```

Sharing and all those things are fine..Now am facing problem..Suppose Ios6 device have no facebook application is installed then safari is using for loading sdk..if Ios6 have facebook application then sdk is open through native app.Then i am trying to login sdk through  native app ,it goes to my home page(Logined user time line) not goes to permission and allthose things..what i am missing?

Comment: ios 6 have in built facebook app.so there is no need to open the facebook sdk i n safari you have to check the ios version.

Comment: but my problem is..When am trying to login it goes to home page not permission page..

Comment: use  "fbconnect api" its easy to use